# Why VM Debugger in Visual Studio 2008 throws "unable to detected startup project"?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, virtual-machine, vmware

I have a problem with VM-Debugger in Visual Studio 2008 (VMWare Workstation 6.5.3). Always when i try to Start the VM-debugging the debugger tells me the following:

```
Error: Unable to detect the current startup project.
```

I only have one startup-project but there are several other projects are in my solution.

The debugger-log says only this:

```
27.10.2009 14:35:29: 
27.10.2009 14:35:29: Debugging started...
27.10.2009 14:35:29: ERROR: pEnumerator->Reset()
27.10.2009 14:35:29: An error occurred in .\Connect.cpp at line 2369.
27.10.2009 14:35:29: ERROR: FindProject(pEV, startupName, pProject)
27.10.2009 14:35:29: An error occurred in .\Connect.cpp at line 2412.
27.10.2009 14:35:30: Error: Unable to detect the current startup project.
27.10.2009 14:35:30: ERROR: DoStart()
27.10.2009 14:35:30: An error occurred in .\Connect.cpp at line 549.
```

The logs of VMWARE-Workstation-Program say nothing that seems like an error.

I already have tried to build a new solution and add my existing projects, but the same effect appears. I already have re-installed the vmware-visual-studio-plugin. There was noch change.

Do you perhaps know what's the problem and how it could be fixed.

Greetings, Martin

Answer (score 1):

It appears that this is a known issue. However, as far I know, VMWare has not released a fix for this even when there have been reports about this since 2 years.

May be your startup project is under a solution folder. On this case, a workaround is to place your startup project at the main level of your solution.

Depending on the structure of your solution, this workaround may be useful or may not work.

For me, even with this workaround, VM-Debugger reuses to work. On my solution, VM-Debugger only worked with the project that is created on a fresh solution (the very, very first project on any solution). Since we removed that project from our solution, it doesn't matter what we do, VM-Debugger simply does not work.

Answer (score 0):

"One more minor note:  If you install VMWare 6.5, it will re-map F6 to "Start debugging in a virtual machine," causing an "Unable to detect the current startup project" error dialog to appear.  To correct this, re-map F6 back to Build.BuildSolution. "

(taken from http://mark.michaelis.net/Blog/VisualStudioKeyboardShortcutsForCompilingMSDNFlashDec292008.aspx)

Maybe this will be helpful.

Comment: I also found this link, but this is not what I want. I want F6 to startup the vm debugger and not the solution build. But if I press F6 to run my software in a vm visual studio tells me the message "unable to detect...". The problem occurs when I try to open up the vm-debugger-config in visual studio, too.